# Incremental Backup With MysqlBackup 3.8.1

Tags: mysql-backup

I want to make a Incremental backup of my database,and for that i am using mysql Enterprise backup.The problem is that when I write down the command

> mysqlbackup --user=root --password=password --backup-dir=/home/admin/Fullbackup backup-and-apply-log

it's all fine,and the full backup is taken finely. But When i Write

> mysqlbackup --user=root --password=password  --incremental --incremental-base=/home/admin/Fullbackup  --incremental-backup-dir=/home/joy/incremental_1 backup

it acts as same,and make the full backup.I tried a lot to identify why it is happening,but I failed :(
Can anyone please help??Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have just got what was my problem,my problem was that,in my database,all the table was type MYISAM, not-innodb .The mysqlbackup command makes incremental backup in case of innodb tables. If we gonna take the incremental backup of the database containing MYISAM table,the entire database(files) will be copied